# Do we need [pip] and [pip3]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip) is a well-used tag about the Python package manager known as `pip`. It has roughly 7,000 questions, a summary, and a tag wiki. Meanwhile, [pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip3), intended to be used for [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip) questions targeting Python 3, has no summary and 12 questions, with the tag wiki stating simply

> pip3 is the [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip) package management system used to install and manage software packages in Python 3.

That is, `pip3` is simply `pip` but built for Python 3 rather than 2.

My suggestion is to merge `pip3` into `pip` and rid ourselves of a relatively pointless distinction. Since we already have [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)  and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) for specifying versions, tagging with [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) *and* [pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip3) is simply redundant.

Comment: Yes, we need it.

Comment: This question would benefit from clarifying whether pip3 and pip are actually different programs, or if they're basically the same program with a different Python version number baked into the executable. I believe that the latter is the case, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It is indeed the latter. I have added a clarification.

Comment: I've made `pip3` a synonym of `pip`.

Answer (score 27):

No, we don't need both [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip) and [pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip3).

Though, [pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip3) doesn't need to be burninated - just make it a synonym of [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip). There is no program called `pip3`. `pip` is a Python package that can be executed as

```
pythonN.M -mpip
```

*This* then usually has a wrapper script that is named `pip` (`pip.exe` on Windows). Now, especially on Linux and Mac distributions the system might support several Python versions at the same time, so the operating system *vendors* might want to provide a wrapper for each version. Therefore the wrapper that executes the equivalent of `python3.6 -mpip` could be named `/usr/bin/pip3.6` and the one that executes `python2.7 -mpip` could then be named for example `/usr/bin/pip2`.

This does not change the fact that it is the very same *package*, with the very same source code, [that can be installed from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) into *both* Python 2 and Python 3. It, very specifically, isn't even *"a pip built for Python 3 rather than 2"*. Instead it is (sorry for a bad analogue) rather like [mozilla-firefox-windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla-firefox-windows-10) vs [mozilla-firefox-windows-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mozilla-firefox-windows-8).

Since the removal of the tag would probably mean that it would be recreated again, I suggest that just a simple synonym would do here. Alas, it is a version synonym so only a moderator can do it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have actually pip3 and pip3.7, both in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/ --> how do  I can delete one of them? (I guess the 2nd one) -- Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm not convinced that removing [pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pip3) will solve any actual problems, nor will it make figuring out which one to use any simpler.  It might actually make things *worse*.

I'd actually say that we don't want to do anything with the tag *right now* except for add a tag wiki and excerpt, since soon enough, Python 2 and pip will be end-of-life, and Python 3 and pip3 will continue onwards (and no one has suggested anything of a rebranding for pip when that happens).

Comment: -1 for the incorrect statement that "soon enough, ... pip will be end-of-life, and ... pip3 will continue onwards."  See Antti Haapala's answer for the way things actually work.

Comment: @jwodder:  The fact that Python 2 is going to be EOL is definitely true.  Let's hope that we don't have any questions pop up that are related to pip2 in 2020.